# Python Polars ComputeError when reading pickle file

Tags: python, python-polars

When I try to execute the snippet below:

```
import pickle

f = open('my_file_path.pkl', 'rb')
loaded_obj = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ComputeError: out-of-spec: Unable to get root as message: {err:?}
```

At first I thought that this was an issue with Pickle and its .load() method, but after reading the error trail this is actually related to Polars, as the last line of the error chain is from \polars package:

```
File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\polars\series\series.py:436 in __setstate__
  self._s.__setstate__(state)
```

The awkward behavior is that this exactly same code (not just this snippet, but a whole dashboard design code) was 100% working yesterday. But after I replaced my notebook (and therefore reinstalled anaconda, python and several packages, including Polars) I'm getting the error.

Therefore what I think is that is nothing wrong with the pickle file itself or the code, but anything related to any update on a package (Pickle, Polars?) that is affecting the execution now?

Thank you.

Comment: did you save the pickle file with different versions of your packages? if so, it might be hard to read it again. I'd suggest choosing a better format (like parquet, json, or even csv) to save data, pickle is the last resort

Comment: Yes, @ignoring_gravity, I did. Ok, thank you for the comments.